# Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR5 incompatibility with latest version of Spring Cloud Schema Registry (2.2.1.RELEASE)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Our microservice implementation is currently on Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR4`, and we have been able to successfully process Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis requests (sending Avro messages) while using Spring Boot `2.2.8.RELEASE`. However, after upgrading to Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR5`, we are now seeing the exception stack trace below, indicating to me that there may be an incompatibility between Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR5` and `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-schema:2.2.1.RELEASE`, the latest release for `spring-cloud-stream-schema` I see available in Maven Central. After encountering these exceptions, I reverted back to `Hoxton.SR4` and everything worked as expected again. Has anyone else encountered this issue or can help explain what may be the incompatibility or problem? Is there an upcoming release of `spring-cloud-stream-schema` that will address this issue?

---

We're currently using `org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.2` to code-gen Java classes from our Avro schemas.

I'm seeing the following log entry in my schema registry server (i.e., my microservice annotated with `@EnableSchemaRegistryServer`:

```
2020-06-15 | 20:18:24.214 | XNIO-1 task-1        |  WARN | .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver | Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
```

And following is the stack trace in my schema registry client (i.e., my microservice annotated with `@EnableSchemaRegistryClient`:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'account-request'; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type: [<Map><timestamp>2020-06-15T23:32:03.766+0000</timestamp><status>415</status><error>Unsupported Media Type</error><message>Unsupported Media Type</message><path>/</path></Map>], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=OMMITTED_FOR_SECURITY_REASONS]
    at com.example.exception.response.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handle(RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:139)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'account-request'; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type: [<Map><timestamp>2020-06-15T23:32:03.766+0000</timestamp><status>415</status><error>Unsupported Media Type</error><message>Unsupported Media Type</message><path>/</path></Map>]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInDeliveryExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:483)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at com.example.rest.AccountRestController.createAccount(AccountRestController.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.execute(MethodExecutionAction.java:116)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.executeWithArgs(MethodExecutionAction.java:93)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.MethodExecutionAction.execute(MethodExecutionAction.java:78)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand$1.execute(GenericCommand.java:48)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.AbstractHystrixCommand.process(AbstractHystrixCommand.java:145)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand.run(GenericCommand.java:45)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
    at org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextCallable.call(DelegatingSecurityContextCallable.java:87)
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceCallable.call(TraceCallable.java:71)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type: [<Map><timestamp>2020-06-15T23:32:03.766+0000</timestamp><status>415</status><error>Unsupported Media Type</error><message>Unsupported Media Type</message><path>/</path></Map>]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:449)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.client.DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.register(DefaultSchemaRegistryClient.java:69)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.resolveSchemaForWriting(AvroSchemaRegistryClientMessageConverter.java:308)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.schema.avro.AbstractAvroMessageConverter.convertToInternal(AbstractAvroMessageConverter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.toMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:207)
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter.toMessage(CompositeMessageConverter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$OutboundContentTypeConvertingInterceptor.doPreSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.MessageConverterConfigurer$AbstractContentTypeInterceptor.preSend(MessageConverterConfigurer.java:295)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorList.preSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:613)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:443)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can anyone from the Spring team tell me if this is related? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-schema-registry/issues/19

Answer (score 1):

The schema registry project has been moved out of the spring-cloud-stream into a top level project: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-schema-registry

So for Spring Cloud `Hoxton.SR5` the compatible registry version is `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-schema-registry-parent:1.0.5.RELEASE`.

Give it a try but mind that `1.0.5.RELEASE` is still at `avro:1.8.2`. 
If you encounter Avro related issues, you can try the `1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`(at `avro:1.9.2`) and please [submit an issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-schema-registry/issues) to either update 1.0.x with avro:1.9.2 of make a 1.1.x release.

Comment: After updating my dependencies and versions to those you referenced, I'm still getting the same 415 error in my client and seeing ```Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
``` on my schema registry server. Any idea what this could still be?

Comment: So, after removing the ```org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-schema:2.2.1.RELEASE``` dependency and pulling in the ```org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-schema-registry-client``` and ```org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-schema-registry-server``` dependencies across my clients and server, I can only get our services working with the Hoxton.SR4 and Spring Boot 2.2.8.RELEASE dependencies specified. Upgrades to the versions of these dependencies introduces the content type errors. I tried Hoxton.SR5 with Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE (and 2.3.1.RELEASE) and couldn't get it working.

Comment: It appears that the 1.0.6.RELEASE may address the issue reported here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-schema-registry/issues/19. Looking at the source code here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-schema-registry/commit/eba9ec89e06cc5415df5348155eefd1f054a0889#diff-abf5fb5e027785cea393d73ce7f226d0. So, do we just need to wait to upgrade to Hoxton.SR5/Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE until Spring Cloud Schema Registry 1.0.6.RELEASE is available? Will that resolve the issue I'm currently encountering?

Comment: @KeithBennett The #19 issues mentioned above is resolved in the master branch, e.g. `1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`, with couple of other fixes such as `avro:1.9.2` upgrade. 
For the sake of the experiment, you can test the 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT build by adding the the Spring snapshot repository to your maven repositories list:

`
<repository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
   <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
`

Comment: Will the 1.1.0 release be coordinated with any upcoming Spring Cloud releases? If so, which Spring Cloud release do you expect it will be coordinated with? We don't have the ability to access the Spring snapshot repository within the environment I work in, so unfortunately I'll have to wait until the release is generally available in Maven Central.

Comment: Do you know ehen the 1.1.0 release will be coordinated with upcoming Spring Cloud releases?