# Spring Cloud Stream is generating Avro Schema in Confluent Schema Registry without any fields

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, confluent-schema-registry

#### Project Description

I have a stream in Spring Cloud Data Flow that source's from a Kafka topic with an Avro schema (by way of Confluent Schema Registry), does some lightweight processing, then sinks to another topic.

#### Problem Description

Consuming from the first topic works great, and is verified in the logs. However, when I try to produce to the second topic, it doesn't work. If I set `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.auto.register.schemas` to true, then it returns this exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: "bytes", failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[214], headers={deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=, kafka_receivedTopic=<my-source-topic>, target-protocol=kafka, kafka_offset=10209, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@180bdb9b, id=fbb4b321-0ece-f5c1-2399-29a1f41cd024, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1630351912519, contentType=application/avro, kafka_groupId=<my-scdf-stream-name>, timestamp=1630352217225}
…
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error registering Avro schema: "bytes"
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema; error code: 409
```

If I set `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.auto.register.schemas` to false, I get this instead:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema: "bytes"
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
```

If I delete the existing schemas in the schema registry and try again, with `auto.register.schemas` set to true instead, then this is what it shows as the schema it's generating for me:

```
{"subject":"<my-sink-topic>-value","version":12,"id":28,"schema":"\"bytes\""}
```

NOTE: When I see `Error retrieving Avro schema: "bytes"`, it makes me wonder if something is off there, which is why it is generating a subject in Schema registry with just `"bytes"` as the schema. Is this indicating what is going wrong here?

Whatever the case is, records now show up in the topic, and are just a single string with no fields, i.e., something like this:

```
null    "R220e2388-60ef-4887-b766-9f11ffa948a7\fcreate\u0010<schema-name>\u0000\u0002\u0012Kalamazoo\u0000\u0000\u0002\u00142021-07-07\u0002\u00142021-07-07\u0002\u0012fake-dataB61138 \u0000\u0002\u00142021-07-07\u0002\n49006"
```

(`null` part is the key, which is somewhat to be expected, given that there's no key). But this is very different from what it should be (note that I'm using the `kafka-avro-console-consumer` to consume this topic).

This is what my processor Java code looks like:

```
  @Bean
  public Function<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> process() {
    return genericRecord -> {
      try {
        logger.info(genericRecord.toString());
        genericRecord.put("val", "fake-data");


      } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to process record");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return genericRecord;
    };
  }
}
```

It seems that something is happening in Spring that makes it so that the schema is not being generated for this GenericRecord properly.

Any ideas on why the write schema generated for these GenericRecords have no fields?

#### Relevant Resources

I checked the following guides and posts, but as far as I can tell I'm doing things according to what it says there:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-schema-registry/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-schema-registry.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-schema-registration-process
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804140/6952495

#### Some of the relevant configs:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/*+avro
```

#### Sample code for reproducing the issue:

https://github.com/Anant/avro-scdf-schema-registry

Comment: Are you using Confluent schema registry? Could you give us more details about your configuration or better yet, provide a complete reproducible sample so that we can triage the issue further?

Comment: @sobychacko yes to Confluent schema registry; I edited my question to make that clearer. I can provide any config info you need, but basically followed [this guide](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-sample/) and so using dependency versions as shown [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/blob/f2b8d5b2fc5ab5da663537da4d143a886f392831/dataflow-website/stream-developer-guides/streams/standalone-stream-sample/pom.xml).

Comment: @sobychacko Here is code to reproduce the issue, instructions are given in the README: https://github.com/Anant/avro-scdf-schema-registry. I will put in the question as well

Comment: Looking at the code again, I wonder if the issue is related to the dependency `spring-cloud-stream-schema` version? I have it set to latest (2.2.1.RELEASE), which makes me think it might be related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411693/6952495). However trying with `spring-cloud-schema-registry` gives same result (I made [a separate branch for this](https://github.com/Anant/avro-scdf-schema-registry/tree/spring-cloud-schema-registry-client))

Comment: Hi, I haven't gotten a chance to run your sample yet. But, since you are using Confluent Schema Registry, you don't need `spring-cloud-schema-registry` (or any Spring Cloud Schema Registry components) as a dependency. I will run your sample soon, but you can take a look at these samples as well: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/schema-registry-samples

Comment: @sobychacko Thanks for the tip, I used the examples link you provided in your comment to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that we needed to set `useNativeEncoding` as true, as per [this example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/schema-registry-samples/schema-registry-confluent-avro-serializer/schema-registry-confluent-avro-serializer-producer2/src/main/resources/application.yml#L8).

For the relevant documentation, see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_producer_properties